# android - UsbManager.getDeviceList() returns empty for some devices

Tags: android, usb

I have an android app that enumerates the USB bus and searches for devices.
When I connect disk-on-key or arduino board to the bus, the app manages to detect and enumerates the connected device. But when i use HID (keyboard and mouse usb dongle), the app does not enumerate it - although the phone recognizes the dongle and I can use the keyboard and mouse
Same enumeration failure occures on another usb device (an RF dongle), but for it I can't tell if it works or not (maybe the device firmware needs to be adjusted).

Things i did so far:
 * Added the  to the Android Manifest.
 * Checked that android.hardware.usb.host.xml exists on the Android
   device in the folder /system/etc/permissions.

I have no idea what is wrong, because I do manage to work with some devices, but not with others.

thanks

Comment: Update: when I checked the connected usb devices in a linux terminal, with the lsusb command, I managed to see my device connected. So I am sure that the device's firmware works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the HID class was blocked by the UsbManager.java

```
   /* returns true if the USB device should not be accessible by applications */
private boolean isBlackListed(int clazz, int subClass, int protocol) {
    // blacklist hubs
    if (clazz == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HUB) return true;
    // blacklist HID boot devices (mouse and keyboard)
    if (clazz == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID &&
            subClass == UsbConstants.USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And is it RFcat the RF dongle you mentioned? I had the same problem, I will try to use the Xposed to replace the method "isBlackListed" by always return false. I will let you know after I have a try.